# Find the conditional density function for the following experiment

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

"A dart is thrown at a circular target of radius $10$ inches, given that it falls in the upper half of the target."

I know that a conditional density function is given by the formula 
$$f(x|E) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x)}{P(E)}, & \text{if $x$ is in E} \\\\
0, & \text{if $x$ is not in E}
\end{cases}$$

Now from what I understand, all you do is restrict the unconditional probability density function to the new domain (i.e. divide by $1/2$ because it is half the board). But other than that I'm not sure what to do...

I know the fact that $x^2+y^2 < 10^2$ and thought about integrating using polar coordinates:
$$f(x)=\int_0^\pi \int_0^{10} r drd\theta = 50\pi$$ to get the density function for the top half of the board. But I know this answer is wrong (correct answer is $\frac\pi{50}$) and I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: Are you sure that the correct answer is $π/50$ and not $1/(π50)$?

Comment: The answer book has π/50 so I believe it is correct. But these things are also known to occasionally have errors so...

Comment: Ok, I find $1/π50$ so perhaps I am wrong. But you should have all the time f(x,y) and not just f(x). Isn't it so?

Comment: @Stefanos Yes, I believe you are correct that it should be f(x,y)

Comment: Did you also check the 1/50π instead of π/50. Because I have an answer with 1/50π but since you say otherwise, I think that I am wrong

Comment: I didn't check it, but that's because I'm not really sure how to do this problem. How are you getting 1/(50π)?

Comment: Ok, you can see my answer. Please check if you find any mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not stated in the exercise, we can arrive to the correct answer if we assume that $(X,Y)$ is a uniformly distributed random vector in the circle with radius $r=10$. In that case $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{10^2\pi}$$ for all $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2\le 10$. Then $$f(x,y|E) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x,y)}{P(E)}, & \text{if } (x,y) \in E \\\\
0, & \text{if }(x,y)\notin E
\end{cases}$$ which implies that $$f(x,y|E) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\frac{1}{100π}}{\frac{1}{2}}, & \text{if }(x,y)\in E \\\\
0, & \text{if }(x,y)\notin E
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{50π}, & \text{if }(x,y) \in E \\\\
0, & \text{if }(x,y)\notin E
\end{cases} $$